# Как сделать проверку на инпут если длина больше 2 добавлять ( / ) если нет убирать или ничего не делать

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-form

Есть инпут

```
<div class="ui-expire-date half right date">
                      <input required id="date" type="tel"  onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'MM/YY'" class="onlyNum" name="DateTo" prev="CardNumber" tabindex="3" placeholder="MM/YY" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5">
                    </div>
введите сюда код
```

как сделать что бы после первых 2 чисел подставлялся ( / )?

Делаю вот так не работает

```
    function addSlesh(){
  var inputSlash = $('#date');
  console.log(inputSlash);
  if(inputSlash.val().length > 2){
    inputSlash.val() = '/';
  }
```

Comment: Плагин inputMask для JS

Comment: мне не плагин нужен) а js  или же jQuery

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы после ввода, напрмер "25", отображалось "25/"?

Comment: @Vincent  треба щоб коли я вводив  місяць і рік вийшло ось так 11/18  після 2 чисел підставлявся /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input=document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keyup",addSlash);

function addSlash() {
  var str=input.value;
  if(str.length>2 && str[2]!="/") {
    input.value=str.substr(0,2)+"/"+str.substr(2)
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```